# Cats awake on home planet while asleep on earth

Tags: story-identification

I read somewhere that there is a book or perhaps a short story, written possibly by Philip K. Dick, where at least part of the story includes the premise that when our cats are asleep here on Earth, they are actually awake on their home planet and vice versa. Does anyone know of this story? I would really like to find it.

Comment: Sounds like H.P. Lovecraft's "The Dreamquest of Unknown Kadath" - cats are intelligent and noble in the Dreamlands.

Comment: Another possibility is HPL's "The Cats of Ulthar." Not enough info to distinguish.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is from [The Sandman: Dream Country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandman:_Dream_Country) (the third volume I think) and the story is called: A Dream Of A Thousand Cats.

> Dream presents her with a vision of an alternate reality where cats are huge and humans are merely their playthings, tiny servants which groom their bodies and which the cats can kill at their leisure. A man ruined that world by informing the humans that their dreams will shape the world. Enough humans listened to make the vision a reality. Upon waking, the cat undertakes a spiritual quest for justice. She preaches her vision to motley assortments of housecats around the world, hoping that if she can make enough cats believe in and dream of this reality, the world will change to conform to their dreams.